# Using filter on Objects in an Array to find max? [swift]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, filtering

I have a bunch of Objects stored in an Array.

They all have the property:

```
distanceInSeconds: Int
```

I was wondering if there's a way to find the max of this property between all objects in the array using filter or another array method?

For instance:

```
var distances: [Distance] = []
var maxDistance = distances.filter(find max)
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be the Swifty way (by implementing `Comparable`):

```
class Route : Comparable {
    let distance: Int

    init(distance: Int) {
        self.distance = distance
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
    return lhs.distance == rhs.distance
}

func <(lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
    return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
}

let routes = [
    Route(distance: 4),
    Route(distance: 8),
    Route(distance: 2),
    Route(distance: 7)
]

print(routes.maxElement()?.distance)
```

output:

```
"8"
```

This works with Swift 2. If you're using Swift 1.2, `maxElement(routes)` should work

Comment: What am I doing wrong? When I implement this class it says it's not conforming to the protocol?

Comment: @KristoferDoman Maybe you implemented it within the class itself, but because it's an operator requirement, it has to be global. Does my code not work for you? It's tested with Swift 2

Comment: It doesn't seem to be, and no, I implemented it outside the class. Do both of them need to be implemented in order for it to conform to protocol?

Comment: I'm also using 1.2, I'm unsure if there's any major differences in this regard.

Comment: @KristoferDoman I really don't know what your problem is, I just tried it with Swift 1.2 in a Playground and it was working just fine (exchanging the last line with `print(maxElement(routes).distance)`)

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2.0 minElement and maxElement now return optionals in case of empty sequences, and also now have versions that take isOrderedBefore closures.

```
    let maxDistance = distances.maxElement { (a, b) -> Bool in
        a.distanceInSeconds < b.distanceInSeconds
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### #1. The element type inside your sequence conforms to `Comparable` protocol

With Swift 4, if the element type inside your sequence conforms to `Comparable` protocol, you will be able to use the `max()` method that has the following declaration:

```
func max() -> Self.Element?
```

> Returns the maximum element in the sequence.

*Usage:*

```
class Distance: Comparable, CustomStringConvertible {

    let distanceInSeconds: Int
    var description: String { return "Distance in Int: \(distanceInSeconds)" }

    init(distanceInSeconds: Int) {
        self.distanceInSeconds = distanceInSeconds
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Distance, rhs: Distance) -> Bool {
        return lhs.distanceInSeconds == rhs.distanceInSeconds
    }

    static func <(lhs: Distance, rhs: Distance) -> Bool {
        return lhs.distanceInSeconds < rhs.distanceInSeconds
    }

}

let distances = [
    Distance(distanceInSeconds: 20),
    Distance(distanceInSeconds: 30),
    Distance(distanceInSeconds: 10)
]

let maxDistance = distances.max()
print(String(describing: maxDistance)) // prints: Optional(Distance in Int: 30)
```

---

### #2. The element type inside your sequence does not conform to `Comparable` protocol

With Swift 4, if the element type inside your sequence does not conform to `Comparable` protocol, you will have to use the `max(by:)` method that has the following declaration:

```
func max(by areInIncreasingOrder: ((offset: Int, element: Base.Element), (offset: Int, element: Base.Element)) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> (offset: Int, element: Base.Element)?
```

> Returns the maximum element in the sequence, using the given predicate as the comparison between elements.

*Usage:*

```
class Distance: CustomStringConvertible {

    let distanceInSeconds: Int
    var description: String { return "Distance in Int: \(distanceInSeconds)" }

    init(distanceInSeconds: Int) {
        self.distanceInSeconds = distanceInSeconds
    }

}

let distances = [
    Distance(distanceInSeconds: 20),
    Distance(distanceInSeconds: 30),
    Distance(distanceInSeconds: 10)
]

let maxDistance = distances.max (by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.distanceInSeconds < b.distanceInSeconds
})

print(String(describing: maxDistance)) // prints: Optional(Distance in Int: 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want reduce:

Setup:

```
struct Distance {
    var distanceInSeconds: Int
}

var distances: [Distance] = []
for _ in 1...10 {
    distances += [Distance(distanceInSeconds: Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))]
}
```

Implementation:

```
let max = distances.reduce(distances.first) {
    if let left = $0 where left.distanceInSeconds > $1.distanceInSeconds {
        return $0
    } else {
        return $1
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty close. Should be:  `...  if $0.distanceInSeconds < $1.distanceInSeconds { ...` – also, the reduce(_) argument should be a distance object with 0 distanceInSeconds

Comment: $0 says it's of type Int, and $1 says it's of type Distance, so there's a flaw there I think.

Comment: Where he has put $0.distanceInSeconds it should just be $0

Comment: Thanks all, was typing from memory!  This one should work!

Comment: Sorry; I realised later that the reduce argument should not be 0, but a distance object with 0 distanceInSeconds

Comment: Since it's of type `Int`, the initial argument should probably be `Int.min` (although, maybe what you actually want is to make `distanceInSeconds` of type `UInt`)

Comment: Good suggestion @nsm - I'll make that

Comment: On second thought, this still fails (returning the junk instance used to start the list) if all of your values are `Int.min` - if you want one of the instances from the list, you could use `<=` to prefer later indices in the list, or start the `reduce` with the first object (the head), and reduce the remaining subarray (the tail). There is also the corner case of an empty list. (probably should return an optional?)

Comment: Okay, @nsm - Since I came this far, I pulled out a playground and made a fully tested, semi-robust working version.